# Show a geometric brownian motion is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{S(t), t\geq0\}$ a geometric brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$. Find if the process is also a martingale or not.

I know that I have to prove that 
$$E[S(t)-S(t-1)\lvert S(t-1),S(t-2),\ldots,S(1),S(0)]=0$$
Or:
$$E[S(t)\lvert S(t-1),S(t-2),\ldots,S(1),S(0)]=S(t-1)$$

But I really have no idea how to attack this problem, any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: But GBM is NOT a martingale.

Comment: I hope this link answers your question. 
@A.S. It is martingale only when drift=0
see http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Geometric.html